# rails - Data insertion within migration don't work

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rails-migrations

I'm trying to insert data with migration and don't understand what's wrong with this code:

```
def change

  create_table :sourcebuster_settings do |t|
    t.integer :session_length
    t.boolean :use_subdomains, default: false
    t.string :main_host

    t.timestamps
  end
  Sourcebuster::Setting.create session_length: 30,
                               use_subdomains: false
end
```

`create_table` works fine, but no data inserted after migration. No errors in console.

Previous migrations with the same method of data insertions works fine also. Problem only with this one.

Comment: are you sure that you're inserting data to the right table? may be `SourcebusterSettings.create ...`

Comment: Yeah. I think it's because of some validations in model. I filled all parameters incl. main_host and data were inserted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it. In my `setting` model:

```
  before_save { self.main_host = main_host.gsub(/(http:|https:|www\.|:|\/)/,'').downcase if self.main_host }

  validates_presence_of :main_host, if: lambda { self.use_subdomains }
  validates :main_host, format: { with: VALID_HOST_REGEX }, allow_blank: true
```

Added `allow_blank: true` to `main_host` validation.